# Need to return the value with an Currency sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I have a small tab on an app that allows user to lookup a price in a price table and it returns the price. how can i get the '$' sign on the returned price?

```
public double? SearchMedicinePrice(Int64 pNDC)
{
    double? retValue = null;
    objConext = new FDBEntities();
    Medicine objMedicine = objConext.Medicines.Where(med => med.PriceType == 9 && med.NDC == pNDC).OrderByDescending(item=>item.MedicineID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (objMedicine != null)
    {
        retValue = objMedicine.Price;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: `double`s cannot have currency signs.

Comment: After you get the price, convert it to a string and prepend the dollar sign.

Comment: the currency symbol is a formatting concern and you can only format strings. as data it's a numeric value.

Comment: Just a recommendation, but using `decimal` would be better than `double` where mathimatical exactness is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `ToString()` on a `double` (and many other types), you can pass in a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to specify how the result should be formatted. Like this:

```
double price = 10.5;
price.ToString("C");
```

Output = `$10.50`

You could also use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) like this:

```
string message = String.Format("The price is {0:C}", SearchMedicinePrice(pndc));
```

`{0:C}` is a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). The `C` specifies that the value should be formatted as currency.

You can also pass in a `CultureInfo` object to configure things like the currency symbol. For example, the following code will output `£10.50`

```
10.5.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

You might also consider using [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of `double` for storing currency data.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a small object:

```
public class Currency {
    public double Amount {get;set;}
    public string Symbol {get;set;}
    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format(Symbol + "{0}",Amount);
    }

}


public Currency SearchMedicinePrice(Int64 pNDC) {
    Currency retValue = null;
    objConext = new FDBEntities();
    Medicine objMedicine = objConext.Medicines.Where(med => med.PriceType == 9 && med.NDC == pNDC).OrderByDescending(item=>item.MedicineID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (objMedicine != null)
    {
        retValue.Amount = objMedicine.Price;
        retValue.Symbol = objMedicine.CurrencySymbol;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Then in to use it:

```
Label1.Text = SearchMedicinePrice(pNDC).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use string

```
string str="$"+SearchMedicinePrice(x).ToString();
```